# Hindu Texts Knowledge Of Things You Can Tell About A Person’s Future & Personality By Their Foot & Face & Body Type

Tags: astrology, body

I understand fate of universe clearly written in planets stars position, for trained Indian people who can actually read that properly from being educated in that stuffs.

Also that fate of a person is very clearly written in lines of their hand.

Apparently the lines of our each foot (?) also give full information of trajectory of our life ?

As well as features of our face & body.

Could someone possibly tell me briefly what are examples of some of the known things you could tell by looking at someone’s eyes, nose, face ?

And with the lines of the bottom of our feet, is more information given there than the lines of our palms ? Curious about this, thank you

Comment: Where did you read this?

Comment: @TerjijKassal I think is common knowledge in Hindu culture ? Am just unsure of the details of the foot part, and also face features